# Possibly simple CSS Resolution to this

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a line of text that wraps to the next lines in a fixed width container that looks like this:

```
Citizens Bank / Greenline Ventures / Local Initiatives Support Corporation (LISC) / Nortridge Software Company / Ohio Capital Corporation for Housing / Oppenheimer Multifamily Housing & Healthcare Finance / PIDC/Portfol / PolicyMap
```

I believe the width is something like 250 pixels wide.  Is there anywhere to ensure that when it wraps to the next line, it doesn't start with a `/`?  For example, If this were to happen...

```
Citizens Bank / Greenline Ventures / Local Initiatives Support Corporation (LISC) 
/ Nortridge Software Company / Ohio Capital Corporation for Housing / Oppenheimer 
Multifamily Housing & Healthcare Finance / PIDC/Portfol / PolicyMap
```

It would need to change it so that the `(LISC)` is on the next line down and in front of the `/` like so:

```
Citizens Bank / Greenline Ventures / Local Initiatives Support Corporation
(LISC) / Nortridge Software Company / Ohio Capital Corporation for Housing / 
Oppenheimer Multifamily Housing & Healthcare Finance / PIDC/Portfol / PolicyMap
```

This is being sent out in an email, so can't use PHP, or anything other than CSS and HTML.  I was thinking of using `white-space: pre`, this this has too many flaws in it, in the sense that it tends to break up the words too much to the next line, for example like this:

```
Citizens Bank / Greenline Ventures / Local Initiatives Support Corporation
(LISC) / 
Nortridge Software Company / Ohio Capital Corporation for Housing / 
Oppenheimer Multifamily Housing & Healthcare Finance / PIDC/Portfol / PolicyMap
```

Where I get strange results from using `white-space: pre` within a `<span>` tag on text.

Also, not sure why, but the `<pre>` tag is not a suitable answer either.  For some reason, wrapping the text within a `<pre>` tag does not always work.  Maybe a another solution?  I think we have to think more aggressive when it comes to laying out things in an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-breaking space in the HTML for the space between the text and the slash.  Then use a normal space for the space after the slash.

```
Citizens Bank&nbsp;/ Greenline Ventures&nbsp;/ ...
```

Comment: Wow, unbelievable, it's just that simple!  Thank you!